# My update function works but it returns an error

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I have an update function for my account in Serializer:

```
class AccountSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    password = serializers.CharField(source="user.password", write_only=True)
    first_name = serializers.CharField(source="user.first_name")
    last_name = serializers.CharField(source="user.last_name")
    email = serializers.EmailField(source="user.username")
    name_extension = serializers.CharField(required=False)
    
    class Meta:
        model = UserDetail
        fields = [
            
            "password",
            "gender",
            "name_extension",
            "email",
            "birth_date",
            "mobile_number",
            "barangay",
            "municipality",
            "province",
            "first_name",
            "last_name",
        ]
    
    def create(self, validated_data):
        try:
            with transaction.atomic():
                verification_token_new = get_random_string(length=22) + date.today().strftime("%Y%m%d")
                user = User.objects.create_user(
                    email=validated_data["user"]["username"],
                    username=validated_data["user"]["username"],
                    password=validated_data["user"]["password"],
                    first_name=validated_data["user"]["first_name"],
                    last_name=validated_data["user"]["last_name"],
                    is_superuser=False,
                    is_staff=False,
                    is_active=False,
                )
                
                Verification.objects.create(
                    user=user,
                    code=verification_token_new,
                )
    
                user_detail_data = {
                    "user": user,
                    "gender": validated_data["gender"],
                    "birth_date": validated_data["birth_date"],
                    "mobile_number": validated_data["mobile_number"],
                    "barangay": validated_data["barangay"],
                    "municipality": validated_data["municipality"],
                    "province": validated_data["province"],
                    "street": validated_data["street"],
                }
    
                if "name_extension" in validated_data:
                    user_detail_data["name_extension"] = validated_data["name_extension"]
    
                UserDetail.objects.create(**user_detail_data)
                
                subject = 'Verify Your Email Address'
                recipient_email = user.email
                register_message_url = os.environ.get('register_message')
                context = {
                    'user': user,
                    'verification_url': str(register_message_url % (str(verification_token_new), user.id))
                }
                print(register_message_url)
                template = 'verification_email.html'
    
                send_email(subject, recipient_email, context, template)
    
                return {
                    "success": True,
                    "message": "User created successfully. Verification email sent.",
                }
    
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error creating user: {e}")
    
            # If any exception occurs, transaction.atomic() will roll back any changes made within its 
            raise serializers.ValidationError({"success": False, "message": f"{e}"})
        
    
    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        try:
            with transaction.atomic():
                user = instance.user
                user.first_name = validated_data.get("first_name", user.first_name)
                user.last_name = validated_data.get("last_name", user.last_name)
                user.email = validated_data.get("email", user.email)
                if 'password' in validated_data:
                    user.set_password(validated_data["password"])
                user.save()
                
                instance.gender = validated_data.get("gender", instance.gender)
                instance.birth_date = validated_data.get("birth_date", instance.birth_date)
                instance.mobile_number = validated_data.get("mobile_number", instance.mobile_number)
                instance.barangay = validated_data.get("barangay", instance.barangay)
                instance.municipality = validated_data.get("municipality", instance.municipality)
                instance.province = validated_data.get("province", instance.province)
                instance.street = validated_data.get("street", instance.street)
    
                instance.name_extension = validated_data.get("name_extension", instance.name_extension)
    
                instance.save()
                return {
                        "success": True,
                        "message": "User created successfully. Verification email sent.",     }
        except KeyError as e:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(f"Missing required field: {e}")
```

it successfully updates but returns an error "Got KeyError when attempting to get a value for field `street` on serializer `AccountSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `dict` instance.
The original exception text was: 'street'."

May I ask for any ideas on how can I fix this?

Comment: The error you’re encountering suggests that the street field is missing from the validated_data dictionary during the update operation. Make sure that the street field is included in the request data when you’re updating the account. If the field is optional, you can provide a default value or handle the case where it’s not present in the request.

Answer (score 0):

The error message you're encountering indicates that the street field is expected in the validated data passed to the serializer but it's missing. This issue arises because the street field is being directly accessed in the create and update methods without checking if it's actually provided in the validated data.

To resolve this issue, you should modify your code to handle cases where street might not be included in the validated data. Here's a way to adjust your update method to handle the absence of the street field:

```
def update(self, instance, validated_data):
try:
    with transaction.atomic():
        user = instance.user
        user.first_name = validated_data.get("user", {}).get("first_name", user.first_name)
        user.last_name = validated_data.get("user", {}).get("last_name", user.last_name)
        user.email = validated_data.get("user", {}).get("username", user.email)  # Assuming `email` is under `user` dict and using `username` key as per your `create` method logic
        if 'user' in validated_data and 'password' in validated_data['user']:
            user.set_password(validated_data["user"]["password"])
        user.save()
        
        instance.gender = validated_data.get("gender", instance.gender)
        instance.birth_date = validated_data.get("birth_date", instance.birth_date)
        instance.mobile_number = validated_data.get("mobile_number", instance.mobile_number)
        instance.barangay = validated_data.get("barangay", instance.barangay)
        instance.municipality = validated_data.get("municipality", instance.municipality)
        instance.province = validated_data.get("province", instance.province)
        
        # Check for 'street' in validated_data before accessing it
        if "street" in validated_data:
            instance.street = validated_data["street"]
        
        if "name_extension" in validated_data:
            instance.name_extension = validated_data["name_extension"]
        
        instance.save()
        return {
                "success": True,
                "message": "User updated successfully.",
               }
except KeyError as e:
    raise serializers.ValidationError(f"Missing required field: {e}")
```

Additionally, ensure that the street field is correctly defined in your UserDetail model and is included in the serializer fields if it's intended to be part of the serialized/deserialized data.

If the street field is optional and not always provided, this approach will help you avoid the KeyError by not trying to access or update the street attribute unless it's explicitly included in the input data.

Comment: It still shows the same error